# Using temporary files safely

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, temporary-files

There is a static library I use in my program which can only take filenames as its input, not actual file contents. There is nothing I can do about the library's source code. So I want to: create a brand-new file, store data to being processed into it, flush it onto the disk(?), pass its name to the library, then delete it.

But I also want this process to be rather secure:
1) the file *must* be created anew, without any bogus data (maybe it's not critical, but whatever);
2) anyone but my process *must not* be able read or write from/to this file (I want the library to process *my* actual data, not bogus data some wiseguy managed to plug in);
3) after I'm done with this file, it *must* be deleted (okay, if someone `TerminateProcess()` me, I guess there is nothing much can be done, but still).

The library seems to use non-Unicode `fopen()` to open the given file though, so I am not quite sure how to handle all this, since the program is intended to run on Windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: What sort of attacks are you expecting? FBI, CIA? Or novice user? What sort of consequences are we talking if the data is indeed corrupted? How long does it take to generate the data for the library?

Comment: Well, the consequences is that annotation to file (which is what that library genenrates) will not match the actual file contents. Unpleasant, but not show-stopping. As for kind of attacks... maybe a sort-of a "destroyer" written by a medium-level hacker/programmer? Not sure what such programs are called exactly - they target a single program and meddle with it/its environment to compromise the result of its work.

Comment: #2 is technically impossible.  All it takes is a process running as an admin and they'll be able to manipulate your file.  You can't lock a user out of his own computer.

Comment: @Corbin, I can't protect myself from anything running with admin rights, and I am not going to even try. But I can, and want to prevent some sneaky trojan horse or whatever to mess with my environment. The question is, how.

Comment: Trojans tend to run with admin rights :).  Anyway, given the constraints of having to use an intermediary file, I have no ideas that are even close to 100% unbreakable :-(.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Technically, even non-admin user privileges are sufficient to cracking this: it's not too hard to intercept calls to the Windows API (say: CreateFile, ReadFile or OpenFile) and inspect/modify the data being passed back and forth.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Surely the OS doesn't allow that? If so, *wow*; seems like that would be very problematic.

Comment: @Corbin: Both Windows as well as Linux allow intercepting calls to libraries. It's commonly used by e.g. Anti-Virus software to monitor the data being read/written.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Ah, I guess it makes sense in the frame of AV. Not sure how I previously thought AV programs worked... haha. Still a bit frightening though :)

Comment: But AV run as services, with elevated rights! And IIRC, there is only one copy of kernel32.dll in the memory, and it's shared by all processes. So I doubt you can inject any hooks into it unless you have admin rights.

Comment: @Joker_vD: You don't need to modify a library in order to intercept calls to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of suggestions already, but another option that I don't think has been mentioned is using named pipes. It will depend on the library in question as to whether it works or not, but it might be worth a try. You can create a named pipe in your application using the `CreateNamedPipe` function, and pass the name of the pipe to the library to operate on (the filename you would pass would be **\\.\pipe\PipeName**). Whether the library accepts a filename like that or not is something you would have to try, but if it works the advantage is your file never has to actually be written to disk.

Comment: Also, the pipe is deleted when closed.

Comment: Oh. Hm, sounds like a good idea, but it seems I can't quite figure out how to write data into a pipe before anyone else connects to it: `WriteFile()` returns `false` and zero in `*lpNumberOfBytesWritten`.

Comment: Pipes operate as a stream with only limited buffering I think, the normal way you would do this would be to 1) create the pipe, 2) launch the library function in a separate thread to read from the pipe, and then 3) write data to the pipe. Again, it really depends on the library as to whether this works or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, the library opens/closes/reopens the file given to it, and it seems to break the pipe... god, am I asking too much: an ability to create a "file", which would be private for the current process? :( But the idea itself is great, I've seen it already in some other project, but forgot about it...

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions (if you don't know if you can write to the current working directory, you may also want to use , [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

1. Determine a directory to store your temporary file in; the current directory (".") or the result of [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be good candidates.
2. Use [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a temporary file name.
3. Finally, call [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create the temporary file.

For the last step, there are a few things to consider:

- The `dwFlagsAndAttributes` parameter of `CreateFile` should probably include `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`.
- The `dwFlagsAndAttributes` parameter should probably also include `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` to make sure that the file gets deleted no matter what (this probably also works if your process crashes, in which case the system closes all handles for you).
- The `dwShareMode` parameter of `CreateFile` should probably be `FILE_SHARE_READ` so that other attempts to open the file will succeed, but *only for reading*. This means that your library code will be able to read the file, but nobody will be able to write to it.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO21-C.+Do+not+create+temporary+files+in+shared+directories) should give you some good guidelines on the issue.

The gist of the matter is this:

- The POSIX [mkstemp()](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html&ei=cDDtUPH-H_CY0QWl4oHgDw&usg=AFQjCNEAPlbY_vFzH8yvG4VUKTwFJn0GGA&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.d2k) function is the secure and preferred solution where available. Unfortunately, it is not available in Windows, so you would need to find a wrapper that properly implements this functionality using Windows API calls.
- On Windows, the [tmpfile_s()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3dz6009.aspx) function is the only one that actually opens the temporary file atomically (instead of simply generating a filename), protecting you from a race condition. Unfortunately, this function does not allow you to specify which directory the file will be created in, which is a potential security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, you can create file in user's temporary folder (eg. C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp) - it is a perfect place for such files. Secondly, when [creating a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx), you can specify, what kind of access sharing do you provide.

Fragment of CreateFile help page on MSDN:

> *dwShareMode*
>
> - **0** Prevents other processes from opening a file or device
>     if they request delete, read, or write access.
> - **FILE_SHARE_DELETE** Enables subsequent open operations on a file or device to
>     request delete access. Otherwise, other processes cannot open the file or device if they
>     request delete access. If this flag is not specified, but the file or device has been opened for delete access, the function fails. Note: Delete access allows both delete and rename operations.
> - **FILE_SHARE_READ** Enables subsequent open operations on a
>     file or device to request read access. Otherwise, other processes cannot open the file or device if they request read access. If this flag is not specified, but the file or device has been opened for read access, the function fails.
> - **FILE_SHARE_WRITE** Enables subsequent open operations on a file or device to request
>     write access. 
>     Otherwise, other processes cannot open the file or device if they
>     request write access.
>     If this flag is not specified, but the file or device has been opened
>     for write access or has a file mapping with write access, the function
>     fails.

Comment: But what if the user's temp directory contains non-ASCII characters, missing from the current locale? And are sharing attributes affect other processes only?

Comment: If you open the file with FILE_SHARE_READ, then as long as you process is holding the file open, no other file can write to the file. But it also means that your library can't write to the file, as it re-opens the same file. (As Frerich Raabe mentions).

Comment: Ooops, forgot to say that it's a *static* library. My bad

Answer (score 0):

Whilst suggestions given are good, such as using FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, etc, I don't think there is a completely safe way to do thist.

I have used Process Explorer to close files that are meant to prevent a second process starting - I did this because the first process got stuck and was "not killable and not dead, but not responding", so I had a valid reason to do this - and I didn't want to reboot the machine at that particular point due to other processes running on the system.

If someone uses a debugger of some sort [including something non-commercial, written specifically for this purpose], attaches to your running process, sets a breakpoint and stops the code, then closes the file you have open, it can write to the file you just created.

You can make it harder, but you can't stop someone with sufficient privileges/skills/capabilities from intercepting your program and manipulating the data.

Note that file/folder protection only works if you reliably know that users don't have privileged accounts on the machine - typical Windows users are either admins right away, or have another account for admin purposes - and I have access to sudo/root on nearly all of the Linux boxes I use at work - there are some fileservers that I don't [and shouldn't] have root access. But all the boxes I use myself or can borrow of testing purposes, I can get to a root environment. This is not very unusual.

A solution I can think of is to find a different library that uses a different interface [or get the sources of the library and modify it so that it]. Not that this prevents a "stop, modify and go" attack using the debugger approach described above.

Answer (score -1):

Create your file in your executable's folder using CreateFile API, You can give the file name some UUID, each time its created, so that no other process can guess the file name to open it. and set its attribute to hidden. After using it, just delete the file .Is it enough?

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but your answer is not very good indeed. You shouldn't create any files in program's folder, because your program may not have rights to do so (UAC, for instance). The Temp folder is meant to be used in such occasions. Applying hidden attribute is a very poor security measure. Only CreateFile API part is OK, as you can specify access flags there, thus preventing other processes from accessing the file.

Comment: Exe s are trusted apps, if it once executed from a path..Am  I right?So will the UAC cause problem..?Temp folder, is not in our control right sometimes, it may get deleted while during a general disk clean up..Yes using file sharing flags is proper way to control the acess, I agree, But uisng UUID as file name and set hidden the file is not that 2 bad..